# Condition number is less than n

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices, condition-number

Show that for an $n$ x $n$ orthogonal matrix $A$ that $\operatorname{Cond}(A) \leq n$.

I need to use:
$$\|x\|_1 \leq \sqrt n$$

I know that $\operatorname{Cond}(A)=1$ for $A$ orthogonal matrix. 
Also given that: $\operatorname{Cond}(A)= \|A\|_1 \cdot \|A^{-1}\|_1$

Comment: This question makes no sense. You know the condition number is 1 and you want to show that it is $\le  n$?

Comment: Yeah, that's the only hint I have

Comment: If you know it is 1 then it must be $\le n$, so there is nothing to show.

Comment: @JeanMarie: You are probably right, but I was hoping for input from the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $A$ is orthogonal, $A^{-1}= A^T$

given $|| x||_1≤\sqrt n$

$Cond(A)= ||A||_1 * ||A^{-1}||_1 = ||A||_1 *||A^T||_1  ≤ \sqrt n * \sqrt n = n$

Comment: May I know why you multiply matrix 1-norm with matrix infinity-norm?

Comment: @dembrownies I edited it, hope it is more clear now

Comment: I know this might sound stupid but why did you replace ||A^T|| 1 norm with ||A|| infinity-norm?

Comment: @dembrownies because infinity norm is the maximum of sum of rows, 1-norm is the maximum of sum of column , when you take transpose, rows become columns.  and do you have the the complete questions? I realized a flaw in the solution: infinity norm is not bounded by $\sqrt n$,

Comment: I edited the question already (with all the hints and complete question)

Comment: ok, I see, maybe the given condition $\|x\|_1 ≤ 1$ means that it is true for both $A$ and $A^T$, then we can skip the infinity norm step, I edited the answer again.